# How to remove lines in a victory chart

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

[image]

I am trying to remove the blue lines to the left of the pink axis, but keep the lines to the right of the pink axis. However I am not sure how to do this using Victory Charts (https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis). Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

This is what I have so far:

```
                <VictoryAxis
                    offsetX={55}
                    verticalAnchor={'start'}
                    name={'vertical-axis-1'}
                    style={{
                        axis: { stroke: 'pink' },
                        grid: { stroke: 'blue', strokeDasharray: '6, 2', strokeWidth: 1 },
                    }}
                    dependentAxis={true}
                    crossAxis={true}
                    tickValues={[22, 30, 37, 45, 52]}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `VictoryAxis` component takes a prop called `style`.

In your code this object has a property called `grid`.

To remove the blue line completely, make the `stroke` value as 'transparent' and remove the `strokeDasharray` and `strokeWidth`. Keeping them will still hide the axis, but you don't need them as there is no stroke.

```
<VictoryAxis
  offsetX={55}
  verticalAnchor={'start'}
  name={'vertical-axis-1'}
  style={{
    axis: { stroke: 'pink' },
    grid: { stroke: 'transparent' },
  }}
  dependentAxis={true}
  crossAxis={true}
  tickValues={[22, 30, 37, 45, 52]}
/>
```

For more customizations using the `style` prop, check the Victory Docs [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-props/#style)